# What to use for the arguments of skimage.measure.moments_central( )?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-image

I am trying to use the measure module of sci-kit image to find the Hu moment invariants of an image, but I am getting stuck on what is going on in one of the prerequisite methods.

The function is defined [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#moments-central) as:

```
skimage.measure.moments_central(image, cr, cc, order=3)
```

where cr and cc are defined to be the center row coordinate and the center column coordinate, respectively. Initially, I thought this just meant the midpoint, but after looking more into the central moment, I'm starting to think that it should be something more along the lines of either the centroid or the geometric center of the object in the image that I am focusing on. Does anyone have any intuition as to what values should be given to cr and cc? The documentation online is very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the centroid of the object of interest. I submitted a fix to improve the documentation with examples, which should also be helpful to you. See: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1636/files.

Usage:

```
>>> image = np.zeros((20, 20), dtype=np.double)
>>> image[13:17, 13:17] = 1
>>> m = moments(image)
>>> cr = m[0, 1] / m[0, 0]
>>> cc = m[1, 0] / m[0, 0]
>>> moments_central(image, cr, cc)
array([[ 16.,   0.,  20.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 20.,   0.,  25.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```